# My Windows Home Server yields nothing when I type ipconfig

Tags: networking, windows-home-server

Even ipconfig /all doesn't yield anything. Does this mean the on-board ethernet is fried?

(Oh, and this is WHS 2008 SP2.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I didn't answer this myself way earlier, but it turns out that WHS didn't plug-and-play the Ethernet drivers. I installed them and then everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible your device is disabled. Check this by clicking your network icon in the tray and selecting "Open Network and Sharing Center" then selecting "Change Adapter Settings" on the left-hand menu. Check to make sure the connection you're interested in is listed there and isn't set to disabled. If it is disabled, right-click on it and you will find an enable option.

You can also get to this screen via Start -> Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center if you have no icon in your tray.

Comment: That was my suspicion as well - I don't even see the NIC in the device manager, though there are three ambiguously-labeled devices that aren't working because they need drivers. Ugh, it's always something with DYI computers.